# CodeIgniter accesing CI super object in core class constructor

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have core class in application/core/MY_Lang.php, this class extends CI_Lang class, and overrides contructor of base class:

```
class MY_Lang extends CI_Lang {
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

How i can access to the database object from constructor of my class.

I tried to access CI super object, but class CI_Controller is not loaded for now

```
    if (class_exists('CI_Controller'))
    {
        $this->CI =& get_instance();
    }
```

Comment: Did you try loading the database object? `$this->load->database();`

Comment: Looking at the base CI_Lang class it seems like get_instance() is being used at least once, so it must be valid to use it in the Lang class. Are you making sure you only use get_instance() _after_ parent constructor is called?

Comment: Actually, have you tried calling get_instance() _without_ first ensuring that CI_Controller exists? I confess, I'm not sure what get_instance() depends on, but it looks like they just call it in CI_Lang without any additional checks in place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, looks like I was wrong about being able to just call get_instance().

But I've found a similar post which suggests using a **post_controller_constructor** "hook" to call your function

See here: [CodeIgniter: get_instance inside My_Lang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7546241/codeigniter-get-instance-inside-my-lang)

The documentation for Code Igniter hooks is here: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user_guide/general/hooks.html

So I'm guessing that in your **application/config/hooks.php** file you want to add something like this:

```
$hook['post_controller_constructor'] = array(
                                'class'    => 'MY_Lang',
                                'function' => '__construct',
                                'filename' => 'MY_Lang.php',
                                'filepath' => 'core',
                                'params'   => array()
                                );
```

I haven't tested this, but let me know if you're not quite getting it to work and I can put together a proper test.

Of course, then in the function you specify in your hook is where you'd want to call **get_instance()** and then load the database library and do whatever work you want.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to use `$this->CI =& get_instance();`, you dont need the other code, as you have `if (class_exists('CI_Controller')) { ... }`

This will allow you to use CI calls such as `$this->CI->load->view`, `$this->CI-load->lang`, etc.

While I have never worked with CI hooks, I don't think this is required or needed for your situation, `$this->CI =& get_instance();` should work fine.

Comment: Did u try test it on local machine?

Comment: I _did_ try this on a local copy of Code Igniter. For me, inside a MY_Lang class, it did not work.